# Fire events on elements that i've changed a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry if i'm doing wrong. That's my first time asking something here.
And i'm sorry for my poor english too.

Look, i'm in trouble. I creating a mini social network only for me and my friends.
I'm new at this jQuery/Ajax thing, so they said that my pages was too static, that anything they had to do, the page was refreshed and this is awful. Then i decided to learn some 'dinamic' stuff and i'm starting to have some problem's with it.

So, i have a "Like-like"(haha) button and i wanted to create a "like(undo)-like" button.

I'll try to simulate my problem:

```
<a class="like">Like</a>
$('.like').click(function(){
     //Like in database
     $(this).html('Like(Undo)');
     $(this).removeClass('like');
     $(this).addClass('like-undo');
});
```

So, when i click, it will trigger the 'like' class action, not the 'like-undo'.
Can anyone help-me? I'm dying already.

I'm sorry if i did something wrong, one more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are bound to elements. When you change the class of an element, that doesn't change which handlers are bound to it. Fortunately for situations like this, you can get that behavior if you use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$('some-common-container').on('click', '.like', function() {
    //...
});

$('some-common-container').on('click', '.like-undo', function() {
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as you said, now your page is dinamic, so you told your js that when they click .like class trigger that function, the problem now is that you are removing the class .like, now it has a class .like-undo so an easy solution would be to add another function to indicate your js what to do if you click .like-undo class

```
$('.like').click(function(){
     //Like in database
    $(this).html('Like(Undo)');
    $(this).removeClass('like');
    $(this).addClass('like-undo');
});

$('.like').click(function(){ //notice you do opossite acctions
   //dislike in database
   $(this).html('Like');
   $(this).removeClass('like-undo');
   $(this).addClass('like');
});
```

Hope it helps!